# On the right adjoint of the derived pushforward of a proper birational morphism of Noetherian quasi-separated schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, adjoint-functors, derived-categories, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a proper birational morphism of Noetherian quas-separated schemes. Let $a: D(QCoh(Y))\to D(QCoh(X))$ be the right-adjoint of the derived pushforward functor $Rf_*: D(QCoh(X))\to D(QCoh(Y))$ (see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A9E) . I have two questions:

(1) Is $a(\mathcal O_Y)\cong \mathcal O_X$ ?

(2) Does $a$ map $D(Coh(Y))$ to $D(Coh(X))$ ?

Comment: @usr0192: If you're talking about Example 48.3.3 in the link, I don't think that morphism is Birational...

Comment: (1) fails even in the simplest case of the blowup of a point on a smooth surface.